# Show specific div on click of list item

Tags: javascript

How to hide other div on click of one of the list item

```
<div id="tab-holder">
<ul id="tabs">
   <li style="margin-top:4px;"><a href="#tab1" class="tab1">Alumni</a></li>
   <li style="margin-top:4px;"><a href="#tab2" class="tab2">Student</a></li>
 </ul>

 <!--TAB1 CONTAINER--> 
 <div id="tab1" class="newscontainer tab1">
      TAB1 CLCIKED  
 </div> 
 <!--TAB1 ENDS-->

 <!--TAB2 CONTAINER--> 
 <div id="tab2" class="newscontainer tab2">
      TAB2 CLCIKED  
 </div> 
 <!--TAB2 ENDS-->
 </div>
```

I need to just show tab1 content on click of Alumni list item ans tab2 on Student list item.
How to do it ?PLease help

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you considered [not reinventing the wheel](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)?

Comment: Please check given answer I think it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#tabs li a").click(function(){
        $(".newscontainer").hide();
        var myDiv = $(this).attr("href");
        $(myDiv).show();
    });
});
```

**Using JavaScript:**

add `onclick` event to your anchor tag like below:

```
<a href="#tab1" class="tabLink tab1" onclick="testFunc(this)">Alumni</a>

<script>
    function testFunc(item) {
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("newscontainer");
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            divs[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        var myDiv = item.href;
        var target = myDiv.split("#");
        document.getElementById(target[1]).style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO-jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBxH8/)

[JSFIDDLE DEMO-JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBxH8/2/)

Comment: Can i do it using javascript and NOT jquery?

Comment: Yes but jQuery is the better option for this requirement.

Comment: Due to some depedency issues am forced to use javascript..:(

Comment: Hey please check my updated answer as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can use below JS

```
$('#tabs > li > a').click(function () {
        $('.newscontainer').hide();
        var $this = $(this);
        var target = $this.attr('href');
        $(target).show();
    });
```

Also can check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/29X4C/4/)

Comment: Can i do it using javascript and NOT jquery?

Comment: Yes let me do the code

Comment: Actually I am not good in JavaScript I need some time to research

Comment: @YogeshSharma already did the code you can check it out my answer.:)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var catchDom = $("#tabs").children();
catchDom.hide();

$("#tab1").click(function () {

    catchDom.hide().eq(0).show();
});
$("#tab2").click(function () {
    catchDom.hide().eq(1).show();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qEjzn/)

Answer (score -1):

```
 $("#tabs li a").on("click",function(){
    var className = $(this).prop("class"); 
    $(".newscontainer").hide();
    $("#"+className).show();
 });
```